# ssl tomcat certificate error

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I followed the following steps at http://www.globalsign.com/support/install/install_tomcat.php, using the following entry in `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
    keystoreFile="D:\Tomcat\ukdp.keystore" keystorePass="123456" keyAlias="ukdp"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

But the following exception occurs during startup:

```
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.io.IOException: Alias name ukdp does not identify a key entry
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:412)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:378)
at 

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:496)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1059)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
Mar 14, 2011 4:14:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
```

When I remove the `keyAlias` entry as follows:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
keystoreFile="D:\Tomcat\ukdp.keystore" keystorePass="123456" 
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

The following exception occurs during startup:

```
SEVERE: Socket accept failed
java.net.SocketException: SSL handshake errorjavax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.acceptSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Mar 14, 2011 4:20:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor run
SEVERE: Socket accept failed
java.net.SocketException: SSL handshake errorjavax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.acceptSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Mar 14, 2011 4:20:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor run
SEVERE: Socket accept failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's in your keystore for a start.

```
keytool -list -keystore D:\Tomcat\ukdp.keystore -storepass 123456
```

If there is really no "udkp" key here's your problem.

Comment: Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

inter, Mar 14, 2011, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 72:82:67:20:5F:EC:F2:9F:4B:9A:3C:08:3D:E5:50:82
ukdp, Mar 14, 2011, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): D5:E8:D3:6E:AB:20:E5:1B:BC:EF:D0:39:B5:AC:37:73

Comment: ukdp is there then why still creating problem

Comment: Hum I fail to see the issue then.

Comment: The JSSE offers very verbose debug message to solve that kind of issue. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug to activate them.

Comment: It turns out that Tomcat requires an entry of _PrivateKeyEntry_, **not** _trustedCertEntry_. The latter you can generate using `keytool -genkey`. I don't know if you can translate from one to the other, but it's a start.

Comment: @jevon: of course, you need the private key to prove you are the holder of the certificate (it's not just Tomcat). No you can't "translate" the certificate into the private key from the certificate only: that's the whole point of asymmetric crypto. If you haven't generated with private key within the keystore in the first place, you can import a private key with a cert into a keystore, but you need to know where it was generated.

Answer (score 16):

List the entires in the keystore using

```
keytool -list -keystore D:\Tomcat\ukdp.keystore -storepass 123456
```

If the entry isn't there, you need to import it as a *PrivateKeyEntry*.
If it's there, see that it's type is *PrivateKeyEntry* and not *trustedCertEntry*.

If the type is *trustedCertEntry* and you want to change it, the process I found is as follows:

```
#Convert to the key type to pkcs12
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey myserverkey.key -in myserver.crt -out tempstore.p12


#Import to keystore:
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tempstore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks

#List:
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
#Note the alias, usually gets "1", we need to change it

#Change alias:
keytool -changealias -alias 1 -destalias mywantedkeyalias -keystore keystore.jks
```

With the obvious changes of *myserverkey.key*, *myserver.crt*, *keystore.jks* and *mywantedkeyalias*

Comment: Is this inconsistent with Bruno's above comment that "you can't translate the certificate into the private key"?

Comment: @MatthewCornell You aren't just translating the certificate, if you can see the first line has two inputs, the certificate file (.crt) and the private key (.key) - they are being converted to the pkcs12 which can then be imported to the keystore as a PrivateKeyEntry (second line).
Does that make sense to you?

Comment: This is almost great but where does `myserverkey.key` come from? All i have is a keystore file