# why doesn't java send the client certificate during SSL handshake?

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, ca

I'm trying to connect to a secure webservice.

I was getting a handshake failure even though my keystore and truststore have been set correctly.

After several days of frustration, endless googling and asking everyone around I found out that the only problem was that java chose not to send the client certificate to the server during the handshake.

Specifically:

1. Server requested a client certificate (CN=RootCA) - i.e. "give me a cert that is signed by the root CA"
2. Java looked into the keystore and only found my client certificate which is signed by the "SubCA", which in turn is issued by the "RootCA". It didn't bother to look into the truststore...duh OK I guess
3. Sadly when I tried to add the "SubCA" certificate to the keystore, that didn't help at all. I did check if the certificates get loaded into the keystore. They do, but the KeyManager ignores all certificates except the client one.
4. All of the above leads to the fact that java decides it doesn't have any certificates that satisfy the server's request and sends nothing...tadaaa handshake failure :-(

My questions:

1. Is it possible that I added the "SubCA" certificate to the keystore in a manner that "broke the certificate chain" or something so that the KeyManager only loads the client certificate and ignores the rest? (Chrome and openssl manage to figure that out so why can't java? - note that the "SubCA" cert is always presented separately as the trusted authority so Chrome apparently correctly packs it along with the client cert during handshake)
2. Is this a formal "configuration issue" on the server side? The server is a third party. I would expect the server to request a certificate signed by the "SubCA" authority since that's what they provided us with. I suspect that the fact that this works in Chrome and openssl is because they are "less restrictive" and java just goes "by the book" and fails.

I did manage to put together a dirty workaround for this, but I'm not very happy about it so I'll be glad if anyone can clarify this one for me.

Comment: It's worth adding to @Bruno's answer that the underlying reason is that there was a private key but no corresponding certificate (i.e. with the same alias), so Java couldn't send one when asked by the `CertificateRequest` messages. Other reasons for this can include no certificate signed by the issuers the server specified, or no certificates matching the ciphers the server specified.

Comment: We solved this issue just matching the ciphers specified by the server. Thanks you guys for all this info, it was very useful.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It's possible that you may have imported the intermediate CA certificate into the keystore without associating it with the entry where you have your client certificate and its private key. You should be able to see this using `keytool -v -list -keystore store.jks`. If you only get one certificate per alias entry, they're not together.

You would need to import your certificate and its chain together into the keystore alias that has your private key.

To find out which keystore alias has the private key, use `keytool -list -keystore store.jks` (I'm assuming JKS store type here). This will tell you something like this:

```
Your keystore contains 1 entry

myalias, Feb 15, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): xxxxxxxx
```

Here, the alias is `myalias`. If you use `-v` in addition to this, you should see `Alias Name: myalias`.

If you don't have it separately already, export your client certificate from the keystore:

```
keytool -exportcert -rfc -file clientcert.pem -keystore store.jks -alias myalias
```

This should give you a PEM file.

Using a text editor (or `cat`), prepare file (let's call it `bundle.pem`) with that client certificate and the intermediate CA certificate (and possibly the root CA certificate itself if you want), so that the client-certificate is at the beginning and its issuer cert is just under.

This should look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICajCCAdOgAwIBAgIBAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVSzEa
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICkjCCAfugAwIBAgIJAKm5bDEMxZd7MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMDsxCzAJBgNV
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now, import this bundle back together into the alias where your private key is:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore store.jks -alias myalias -file bundle.pem
```

Comment: Thanx a million Bruno - that did the job. I think this could be a bit more documented. I just spent several days trying to figure out what the hell is going on. Java's hints were practically non-existent.

Comment: I too need to combine a certificate and private key into the import, but I'm starting with a *.pem certificate file (starts with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----") and a *.key private key ("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"). I tried concatenating them and then importing, but I got: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate . Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297867/ssl-tomcat-certificate-error/11984173#11984173 that might need to convert to the key type pkcs12. Any ideas? I'm stuck! Thank you.

Comment: My 2cts: The private key must be assigned with the WHOLE chain of the public key.In my this case; our public key need to bed assigned with the intermediate and root CA. This PEM file must be loaded into the keystore:
keytool -importcert -keystore store.jks -file bundle.pem -alias myalias
...
.. is not trusted. Install reply anyway? [no]: yes
... 
This wil update (!) the existing key with whole chain.

Comment: You would need to import your certificate and  your private key to a pkcs12 file like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8224863 , worked for me :D

Comment: If the user want to authenticate with a smart card, the private key cannot be exported... there must be some other ways..

Comment: @FaithReaper The smartcard will generally not let you export the private key indeed, but it should let you set the certificate chain. Note that in the above answer, the private key is never exported either: you're just re-importing the chain against the entry that contains both the private key and the certificate chain.

Comment: Anecdata: Make sure you are using the latest possible version of keytool from Java 17+.  Each release of Java makes small internal improvements to this tool.  However, the command line parameters (and online help) remain virtually unchanged.  As I recall, older versions of Java struggle to correctly import a cert *chain*.  Later versions work without any issues.

Comment: @kevinarpe: I never had any problem with keytool importing a chain _to a privatekey_ (i.e. as a CA reply; NOT as a trustedcert) back to Java 5 around 2004. The only thing I experienced is that early versions (through 6 IIRC) couldn't handle PEM files with 'comment' or other lines added above the dash-BEGIN line; openssl often created such files and a few other tools also did (and both still do).

Answer (score 6):

As an add here, you can use *%> openssl s_client -connect host.example.com:443* and see the dump and check that all the main cert is valid against the client.  You are looking for this at the bottom of the output.
    **Verify return code: 0 (ok)**

If you add *-showcerts* it will dump all the info of the keychain that was sent along with the host certificate, which is what you loaded into your keychain.

Comment: @JerylCook `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host.example.com:443`

Comment: How could I add these to truststore jks file?

Comment: The Q is about sending a _client_ cert; it has nothing to do with the server cert. This A is entirely about checking the server cert and completely irrelevant to the Q.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions I've seen revolve around using the **keytool** and none of them matched my case.

Here is a very brief description: I've got a PKCS12 (.p12) which works fine in Postman with disabled certificate verification, however programmatically I always ended up getting server error "400 Bad Request" / "No required SSL certificate was sent".

*The reason was a missing TLS extension SNI (Server Name Indication) and following is the solution.*

---

### Adding an extension/parameter to SSL Context

After SSLContext init, add the following:

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    try (SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port)) {
        SSLParameters sslParameters = socket.getSSLParameters();
        sslParameters.setServerNames(Collections.singletonList(new SNIHostName(hostName)));
        socket.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
        socket.startHandshake();
    }
```

---

### Full HTTP Client class for this case (NOT FOR PRODUCTION)

Note 1: SSLContextException and KeyStoreFactoryException simply extend RuntimeException.

Note 2: Certificate validations are disabled, this example was intended for dev use only.

Note 3: Disabling hostname verification was not required in my case, but I included it as a commented line

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Objects;

public class SecureClientBuilder {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private boolean keyStoreProvided;
    private String keyStorePath;
    private String keyStorePassword;

    public SecureClientBuilder withSocket(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        return this;
    }

    public SecureClientBuilder withKeystore(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword) {
        this.keyStoreProvided = true;
        this.keyStorePath = keyStorePath;
        this.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
        return this;
    }

    public CloseableHttpClient build() {
        SSLContext sslContext = keyStoreProvided
                ? getContextWithCertificate()
                : SSLContexts.createDefault();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory =
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        return HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                //.setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                .build();
    }

    private SSLContext getContextWithCertificate() {
        try {
            // Generate TLS context with specified KeyStore and
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(getKeyManagerFactory().getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[]{getTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());

            SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            try (SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port)) {
                SSLParameters sslParameters = socket.getSSLParameters();
                sslParameters.setServerNames(Collections.singletonList(new SNIHostName(host)));
                socket.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
                socket.startHandshake();
            }

            return sslContext;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | IOException e) {
            throw new SSLContextException("Could not create an SSL context with specified keystore.\nError: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private KeyManagerFactory getKeyManagerFactory() {
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = getResourceFile(keyStorePath)) {
            // Read specified keystore
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(fileInputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

            // Init keystore manager
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            return keyManagerFactory;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | KeyStoreException e) {
            throw new KeyStoreFactoryException("Could not read the specified keystore.\nError: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Bypasses error: "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
    private TrustManager getTrustManager() {
        return new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        };
    }

    private FileInputStream getResourceFile(String keyStorePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        URL resourcePath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(keyStorePath);
        return new FileInputStream(resourcePath.getFile());
    }

}
```

---

### Using the client builder above

Note 1: keystore (.p12) is looked for in "resources" folder.

Note 2: Header "Host" is set to avoid server error "400 - Bad Request".

```
String hostname = "myHost";
int port = 443;
String keyStoreFile = "keystore.p12";
String keyStorePass = "somepassword";
String endpoint = String.format("https://%s:%d/endpoint", host, port);

CloseableHttpClient apacheClient = new SecureClientBuilder()
        .withSocket(hostname, port)
        .withKeystore(keyStoreFile, keyStorePass)
        .build();

HttpGet get = new HttpGet(endpoint);
get.setHeader("Host", hostname + ":" + port);
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = apacheClient.execute(get);

assert httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200;
```

---

### Reference docs

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html

Answer (score -2):

The thing is when using client cert signed by an intermediate one you need to include the intermediate one in your trustore so java can find it. Either solo or as a bundle with the root issuing ca.

Comment: You need to include it in your *keystore*, and the question was correctly answered seven years ago.

Comment: The keystore is for client keys only, ones we use to authenticate to servers. The signing and CA certificate chains should go in the trust store as i said so please stop confusing people. Learn to distinguish between `PrivateKeyEntry` and `trustedCertEntry`.