# Http certificate authentication with HttpUrlConnection from a WebLogic client app

Tags: authentication, weblogic, httpurlconnection, client-certificates

I have a simple client application that downloads data from a site via HttpUrlConnection. The server uses cert auth. The app (outside of Weblogic) works proper. In standalone mode I set the cert via SSLSocketFactory.

But the app have to work inside a WebLogic app server.

I've added the cert to the cacerts (and even into the identity store of the WebLogic). In the log I see WL finds it. But I've got an `RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure` error.

What have I do in a different way? Thanx!

```
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(String[]): value=SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5,SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnabledProtocols(String[]): value=SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnableSessionCreation(boolean):value=true.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setWantClientAuth(boolean): value=false.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(boolean): value=false.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(boolean): value=false.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.>
    Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
    Allow legacy hello messages: true
    Is initial handshake: true
    Is secure renegotiation: false
    %% No cached client session
    *** ClientHello, TLSv1
    RandomCookie:  GMT: 1377072614 bytes = { 22, 18, 8, 150, 85, 185, 67, 160, 51, 252, 172, 191, 141, 100, 201, 254, 187, 63, 235, 175, 246, 17, 165, 128, 216, 209, 228, 102 }
    Session ID:  {}
    Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
    Compression Methods:  { 0 }
    ***
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 75
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 101
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 103.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0.>
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 74
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_TASK bytesConsumed = 79 bytesProduced = 0.>
    *** ServerHello, TLSv1
    RandomCookie:  GMT: 1377072630 bytes = { 90, 186, 22, 195, 56, 131, 89, 24, 40, 175, 153, 6, 104, 172, 220, 160, 93, 105, 251, 97, 118, 101, 103, 72, 243, 179, 201, 87 }
    Session ID:  {146, 153, 76, 87, 103, 112, 44, 239, 163, 85, 147, 205, 99, 91, 81, 62, 74, 79, 82, 96, 106, 103, 78, 165, 35, 242, 44, 71, 227, 192, 111, 253}
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    Compression Method: 0
    ***
    Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
    %% Created:  [Session-3, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
    ** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
    bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0.>
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1667
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_TASK
    bytesConsumed = 1672 bytesProduced = 0.>
    *** Certificate chain
    chain [0] = [
    [
      Version: V3
      Subject: EMAILADDRESS=fomi@takarnet.hu, CN=*.takarnet.hu, O=Foldhivatal, L=Budapest, ST=Hungary, C=HU
      Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4

      Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
      modulus: ************
      public exponent: 65537
      Validity: [From: Tue Sep 14 15:01:48 CEST 2010,
                   To: Fri Dec 11 14:01:48 CET 2037]
      Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=fomi@fomigate.fomi.com, CN=TAKARNET CA, O=FOLDHIVATAL, L=Budapest, ST=Hungary, C=HU
      SerialNumber: [    341c]

    Certificate Extensions: 4
    [1]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13 Criticality=false
    Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************


    [2]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
    NetscapeCertType [
       SSL client
       SSL server
       S/MIME
       Object Signing
    ]

    [3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
    KeyUsage [
      DigitalSignature
      Non_repudiation
      Key_Encipherment
    ]

    [4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
    BasicConstraints:[
      CA:true
      PathLen:2147483647
    ]

    ]
      Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
      Signature:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************

    ]
    chain [1] = [
    [
      Version: V3
      Subject: EMAILADDRESS=fomi@fomigate.fomi.com, CN=TAKARNET CA, O=FOLDHIVATAL, L=Budapest, ST=Hungary, C=HU
      Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4

      Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
      modulus: ************
      public exponent: 65537
      Validity: [From: Tue Feb 12 11:25:51 CET 2002,
                   To: Sat Jun 30 12:25:51 CEST 2029]
      Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=fomi@fomigate.fomi.com, CN=TAKARNET CA, O=FOLDHIVATAL, L=Budapest, ST=Hungary, C=HU
      SerialNumber: [    00]

    Certificate Extensions: 4
    [1]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
    NetscapeCertType [
       SSL server
       SSL CA
       S/MIME CA
    ]

    [2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
    SubjectKeyIdentifier [
    KeyIdentifier [
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    ]
    ]

    [3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
    AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
    KeyIdentifier [
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    ]

    [EMAILADDRESS=fomi@fomigate.fomi.com, CN=TAKARNET CA, O=FOLDHIVATAL, L=Budapest, ST=Hungary, C=HU]
    SerialNumber: [    00]
    ]

    [4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
    BasicConstraints:[
      CA:true
      PathLen:2147483647
    ]

    ]
      Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
      Signature:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************

    ]
    ***
    Found trusted certificate:
    [
    [
      Version: V3
      Subject: EMAILADDRESS=fomi@takarnet.hu, CN=*.takarnet.hu, O=Foldhivatal, L=Budapest, ST=Hungary, C=HU
      Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4

      Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
      modulus: **************
      public exponent: 65537
      Validity: [From: Tue Sep 14 15:01:48 CEST 2010,
                   To: Fri Dec 11 14:01:48 CET 2037]
      Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=fomi@fomigate.fomi.com, CN=TAKARNET CA, O=FOLDHIVATAL, L=Budapest, ST=Hungary, C=HU
      SerialNumber: [    341c]

    Certificate Extensions: 4
    [1]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13 Criticality=false
    Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
    0000: 04 32 16 30 54 68 69 73   20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69  .2.0This Certifi
    0010: 63 61 74 65 20 77 61 73   20 47 65 6E 65 72 61 74  cate was Generat
    0020: 65 64 20 62 79 20 46 6F   6C 64 68 69 76 61 74 61  ed by Foldhivata
    0030: 6C 20 43 41                                        l CA


    [2]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
    NetscapeCertType [
       SSL client
       SSL server
       S/MIME
       Object Signing
    ]

    [3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
    KeyUsage [
      DigitalSignature
      Non_repudiation
      Key_Encipherment
    ]

    [4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
    BasicConstraints:[
      CA:true
      PathLen:2147483647
    ]

    ]
      Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
      Signature:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************

    ]
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 152
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:30 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_TASK bytesConsumed = 157 bytesProduced = 0.>
    *** CertificateRequest
    Cert Types: RSA, DSS, Ephemeral DH (RSA sig)
    Cert Authorities:
    <EMAILADDRESS=***, CN=TAKARNET CA, O=FOLDHIVATAL, L=Budapest, ST=Hungary, C=HU>
    *** ServerHelloDone
    *** Certificate chain
    ***
    *** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 141
    SESSION KEYGEN:
    PreMaster Secret:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    CONNECTION KEYGEN:
    Client Nonce:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    Server Nonce:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    Master Secret:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    Client MAC write Secret:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    Server MAC write Secret:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    Client write key:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    Server write key:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    Client write IV:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    Server write IV:
    0000: ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **  ****************
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
    *** Finished
    verify_data:  { 60, 110, 8, 97, 250, 71, 53, 6, 54, 184, 165, 165 }
    ***
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:31 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 146.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:31 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 6.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:31 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 53.>
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:31 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0.>
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    <2013.08.21. 10:14:31 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Exception occurred during SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]).
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1467)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1435)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1601)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1031)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:845)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:721)
            at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:647)
            at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$5.run(JaSSLEngine.java:134)
            at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:732)
            at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.unwrap(JaSSLEngine.java:132)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrap(JSSEFilterImpl.java:585)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:490)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:93)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:71)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.write(JSSEFilterImpl.java:434)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket$JSSEOutputStream.write(JSSESocket.java:78)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
            at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
            at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:186)
            at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:400)
            at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
```

Comment: I found my answer in another questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875094/ssl-server-socket-want-auth-option Perhaps it will help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to ignore SSL certification verification on weblogic? Just put "-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true" in weblogic's JAVA_OPTIONS and try again.