# Include intermediate chain in keystore for mutual SSL

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've been at this way too long and have searched high and low for a solution.

I am trying to do mutual SSL. The target is using a certificate signed by an intermediate that is valid and trusted. My side, a Java web service client using httpclient 4.3.6, is also using a certificate signed by the intermediate.

The intermediate is in a JKS format keystore and has the full chain. My certificate is also in a JSK keystore.

I am also running Wireshark to follow the SSL process, since the Java exceptions are very unhelpful. I can see that the Server Hello finishes (a line in Wireshark called "Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done"). A couple of packets later, there is a "Certificate, Client Key Exchange" line that *seems* to run ok. Two packets later, there is an alert about a handshake failure (40). When I go backward two packets to the "Certificate, Client Key Exchange" line and inspect it closely, I can see that while the key was sent off, there is a line that says "Certificates Length: 0" in the packet inspection window.

So it appears that my certificate is not even being sent? I saw on another question here that it may be because my side doesn't see a valid path to my cert, and so doesn't bother including it? (The answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876605/5136448). I do include the trust store that has my intermediate in it when using SSLContext and SSLConnectionSocketFactory.

A colleague of mine got a successful connection using openssl when including my keystore and intermediate together, so I'm trying to add the certificate chain from the intermediate keystore to my own keystore to see if that will solve it. I have no found any successful way of doing this (openssl, keytool, Keystore Explorer), so I may not have the right idea as to properly solve this.

To sum up, using Apache http-client 4.3.6, I need to do mutual SSL to a server where the server is trusted, but the client doesn't seem to be sending its certificate (which was signed by the same entity that signed the server's certificate).

Should it be relevant, here is the client-side code:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keystore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/test.keystore")), "abc123".toCharArray());

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/test.truststore")), "123abc".toCharArray());

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
.custom()
.loadKeyMaterial(keystore, "abc123".toCharArray(), null)
.loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, null)
.build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
new String[]{"TLSv1.2"},
null,
SSLConnectionSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);


CloseableHttpClient httpclient1 = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();
```

Comment: Your text says JKS but your code says PKCS12? In your wireshark capture, look at the server's `CertificateRequest` message to see what CAs (if any) it asks for. Look at the privatekey entry in your keystore (only the privatekey entry, not any trustedcert entry, although for PKCS12 this _may_ not matter) with `keytool -list -v` and see if any cert in the chain is issued by a CA the server asked for. If not, that's your problem.

Comment: That was it. The "server" side of this handshake had a cert signed by a different machine (thus a different intermediate) than the one that was signed by my machine. It's working now.