# Why is the apache httpclient giving an SSL error when connecting to a page that has no SSL Certificate?

Tags: java, apache, ssl, authentication, https

I'm trying to log into my school's grade page. So that I can have my program retrieve my current grades. The login page is https://portal.hinsdale86.org/homeaccess , and I have some basic code that first sends a GET to the page. However the program terminates after the SSL error.

```
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://portal.hinsdale86.org/homeaccess");
CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

That last line is where is error occurs.

So basically what I don't understand is why there is an SSL error, where no SSL is involved.

edit:
I appears that I do not get an error when I use the http version of the site. However I would like to use the https version if possible. It does have a trusted certificate from Go Daddy as per what chrome says.

Comment: Your URL starts with `https`. SSL is definitely involved!

Comment: Oh wow, I realized the site has an https and an http version. I tried the http version and didn't get an error.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: I fixed the SSL error by using the http version of the page. Now I get an connection reset error, when I try posting data to login.

Comment: @AS98 Using the plain HTTP version isn't fixing the SSL problem. You're saying in your edit you'd like to use the HTTPS version if possible, yet you're not saying what happens...

Comment: I actually just found out why I'm having this problem with ssl. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746565/godaddy-ssl-cert-not-working-with-java