# Cacerts in a Java program calling https

Tags: java, rest, ssl

I am building an application in Java which I would like to make rest calls to https services. The application is written in Java Standard Edition.

I am using If This Then That as a test but I want the application to connect to any https site that the user types in.
For IFTTT I use the following URL:

```
https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{my_event} /with/key/{my_app_key}
```

I get the following error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I think this error means that the root certificate used for IFTTT is not in my cacerts truststore. I understand a solution to this problem may be to add it. According to chrome the certificate path terminates at a root certificate names “Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority – G2”.

I guess if I add this to my cacerts using keytool it will work. However I expect users of my application to type in various URL’s. I don’t want to only allow a particular subset of the internet. I also don’t want to disable certificate checking.
Chrome, IE and firefox all recognise the IFTTT site without a problem. 
Why doesn’t the standard cacerts file in Java recognise this?
Can I get Java to use a system cacerts file which includes all these sites? (This would have to work on Java on Windows, Max and various Linux flavours.)

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508050/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-trusted-root-certificates-in-java

Comment: Which exact version of Java are you using? You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18746565/372643

Comment: Bruno - your link has the solution, but I can't tick your comment