# Java keyTool - append primary/secondary intermediate certificates to key store

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, append, keytool

I have already created a keystore (server.jks in the image) having imported the relevant key-pair.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.p12 -destkeystore server.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

I need to append intermediate certificates to it using the java keytool.

Using KeyStore explorer tool on windows, I can append certificates following the right click context menu, just like in the attached image.

[image]

After adding the primary/intermediate certificates following the Append Certificate option, I can see it on the KeyStore explorer like a tree.

```
---primary intermediate certificate
     |---secondary intermediate certificate
           |---my server certificate
```

I am very much interested in knowing how this can be done, using the 'Java KeyTool' on the (LINUX) command line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @jww, while it's true it's not purely a programming question, I'd consider `keytool` to be a software tool commonly used by developers, therefore such a question on-topic. Not sure the SF community would like such a question (possibly not "professional" enough), and possibly too specific for SU. I admit it's a grey area, like many SSL-related questions.

Comment: That might not be directly a Programming question. But the Dev ops people usually are familiar with these stuff; programmers are not, even if we have to deal with these stuff usually. I am a programmer, Specially who is working with Middleware. People who work with me mostly visit Stack-overflow for these kind of questions. However, can we move the questions from Stack-overflow to a site like Super user? Because I do not want to delete this after I got the answer, making the person (Bruno) who answered the question losing the credit that he deserves.

Comment: I will add this question to the Super user, this may be deleted from here as I see two votes for closing this question. Bruno, please do provide your answer there. Thanks a lot!!! Find it here http://superuser.com/questions/755148/java-keytool-append-primary-secondary-intermediate-certificates-to-key-store

I did not delete this question by myself, since it is not recommended to delete an answered question.

Comment: Don't worry too much about my potential reputation loss, I can live with that. It's generally better not to ask again on a different site but to ask for it to be moved (flag it), moderators should be able to move questions (with their answers). There are also only 2 closing votes at the moment, even if it reached 5, the question would be closed, not deleted (at least not immediately).

Comment: I agree with @Bruno that the question belongs here rather than elsewhere.

Comment: Bruno and EJP - with all do respect, what's the point of having rules if you are not going to follow them? Developers use lots of tools, but many are not on-topic here either. Its not limited to `keytool`. For what its worth, I did not think it was a bad question. But Stack Overflow rules dictate it belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more or less the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9300727/372643). You need to prepare a file representing the certificate chain, each certificate followed by the CA certificate that issued it.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICajCCAdOgAwIBAgIBAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVSzEa
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICkjCCAfugAwIBAgIJAKm5bDEMxZd7MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMDsxCzAJBgNV
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

You may need to export your EEC (End Entity Certificate) from your keystore first (`keytool -exportcert ...`). Then, use the text editor of your choice (vi, emacs, gedit, ...) or `cat` to concatenate your EEC and the intermediate certificate(s) in order. Then import the resulting file into your keystore against the alias that contains your private key (`keytool -importcert -alias ...`).

Comment: I've been looking for this for ages, your help much appreciated!