# How to configure Tomcat (in Spring Boot) to provide full certificate chain with SSL connections? (currently working with Chromium, not with Firefox)

Tags: spring, google-chrome, tomcat, firefox, ssl

I have the following issue: I have a domain that hosts a) a website on port 443 (Apache) and b) a web app with Spring Boot (Tomcat) on port 8443. Both are using the same certificates. For Tomcat I generated a keystore that consists of the private key/certificate, intermediate and root certificate. Visiting the website is not an issue at all.

Now, when I visit the webapp from e.g. Chromium or from my smartphone I can access it and https works just fine (certificate is trusted and I can view the certificate chain). If I instead try opening it in Firefox or use `openssl s_client -connect domain.com:8443` the connection is not secured and only my certificate, but neither the intermediate and nor the root certificate are provided.

Now I don't understand how that happens, whether maybe Chrome recognizes the certificate chain from the `issuer` field of the certificate or asks the app server to provide further parts of the chain, and Firefox/openssl do not.

Any hint about how to make this running would be greatly appreciated!

BR Johannes

BTW about the keystore creation: I created an empty keystore, added the root, then the intermediate and then my certificate + key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I made a mistake on how to create the keystore, just importing the certificate chain and the key pair wasn't enough. I had to append the certificates of the chain to my certificate (using KeyStoreExplorer or as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686259/java-keytool-append-primary-secondary-intermediate-certificates-to-key-store).

How it came that Chromium accepted the certificate anyway is still a mistery to me, though.

Comment: It would be nice if you added the steps in your answer instead of linking them.