# Install SSL Certificate with its chain in JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final

Tags: openssl, jboss7.x

I have acquired a Signed Certificate from COMODO. There are 4 CRT files. 1 domain, 2 intermediate and 1 root certificate. i have concatenated CRTs into a PEM file and also imported them in CACerts , Trusted Certificates on the OS / JVM.

The certificate does shows up but when i verify i get info like the certificate chain is broken. and the certificate chain is displayed as not trusted on Android devices..

Anyone can share a working solution to this issue. There are numerous examples available on net but none of them works.

Info: the csr is generated with openssl.

Comment: What's the URL of the server? And I'm pretty sure Bruno answered a similar question at [Why doesn't java send the client certificate during SSL handshake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299133/why-doesnt-java-send-the-client-certificate-during-ssl-handshake).

Comment: First, what does the private key have to do with a question about a broken certificate chain? Second, how, exactly, do you expect to provide the private key to JBoss?

Comment: I have a keystore prepared with keytool command. when i list it using keytool -list -v -keystore <> it is listing all the files.

Comment: I get following error Unable to load certificate key ../standalone/configuration/domain.keystore (error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to implement this ?