# XAdES-T over HTTPS

Tags: https, xades4j

I would like to put a XAdES-T signature on an XML file using xades4j. My application works if the timestamp provider is listening on an HTTP URI (e.g. http://tsa.starfieldtech.com/), but I get error messages (s. later) if the timestamp provider needs SSL connection (e.g. **https**://tsa.hiteles.gov.hu/ts).

How should I adjust my code? I have got an SSL certificate from the timestamp provider but I don't know how to use it...

Stacktrace with error details:

```
Exception in thread "main" xades4j.production.PropertyDataGenerationException: Property data generation failed for SignatureTimeStamp: cannot get a time-stamp
    at xades4j.production.DataGenBaseTimeStamp.generatePropertyData(DataGenBaseTimeStamp.java:75)
    at xades4j.production.PropertiesDataObjectsGeneratorImpl.doGenPropsData(PropertiesDataObjectsGeneratorImpl.java:86)
    at xades4j.production.PropertiesDataObjectsGeneratorImpl.genPropsData(PropertiesDataObjectsGeneratorImpl.java:72)
    at xades4j.production.PropertiesDataObjectsGeneratorImpl.generateUnsignedPropertiesData(PropertiesDataObjectsGeneratorImpl.java:64)
    at xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:275)
    at xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:122)
    at xades4j.production.Enveloped.sign(Enveloped.java:68)
    at hu.nisz.eszig.util.XadesTSigner.signXml(XadesTSigner.java:82)
    at hu.nisz.eszig.util.test.XadesTTest.testXadesTSignAndCheckSign(XadesTTest.java:37)
    at hu.nisz.eszig.util.test.XadesTTest.testTesztTankiadoWithStarfield(XadesTTest.java:28)
    at hu.nisz.eszig.util.test.XadesTTest.main(XadesTTest.java:16)
Caused by: xades4j.providers.TimeStampTokenGenerationException: Error when connecting to the TSA
    at xades4j.providers.impl.DefaultTimeStampTokenProvider.getResponse(DefaultTimeStampTokenProvider.java:152)
    at xades4j.providers.impl.DefaultTimeStampTokenProvider.getTimeStampToken(DefaultTimeStampTokenProvider.java:102)
    at xades4j.production.DataGenBaseTimeStamp.generatePropertyData(DataGenBaseTimeStamp.java:60)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at xades4j.providers.impl.DefaultTimeStampTokenProvider.getResponse(DefaultTimeStampTokenProvider.java:138)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 31 more
```

**EDIT 1**:
After I have put

> System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

into my code I get a lot of debug message ending like this:

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 2E                               .......
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

**EDIT 2**:
I have managed to go further by putting the certificates into a truststore but I still have problems with the handshake. I seems to me my client cannot send the server an appropriate certificate:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
...
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have finally manage to solve my problem based on this: [why doesn't java send the client certificate during SSL handshake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299133/why-doesnt-java-send-the-client-certificate-during-ssl-handshake)

To achieve this I needed a truststore (truststore2.jks) containing the server's certificate chain and a keystore (govca_ssl_2.pfx) containing the client's certificate and the private key.