# XML-RPC client not able to send SSL certificate to server

Tags: java, xml-rpc

We have a requirement where we need to call the XML-RPC API of Confluence server to push some data. Our Confluence server is protected by two way SSL authentication (mutual auth). After some searching on internet i got some info on writing an xml-rpc client with SSL properties and then making the API call. But the code is failing with below SSLHandshake error.

```
*** ServerHelloDone
```

[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
**Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication**
*** Certificate chain

---

*** ECDHClientKeyExchange

main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
JavaClient: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Failed to create input stream: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

**Below is my source code** :

```
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;
```

import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * XmlRpc Client with SSL 
 * 
 *
 */
public class XMLRPC_SSL_Client {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl clientConfig = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
        clientConfig.setServerURL(new URL("https://stg.api.collaborate.testing.com/confluence/rpc/xmlrpc"));

        XmlRpcClient xmlRpcClient = new XmlRpcClient();
        xmlRpcClient.setConfig(clientConfig);

        Vector<String> params = new Vector<String>();

        params.add("confadmin1");
        params.add("confadmin1");

        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");

        //Trust srever's certificate
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/Users/aswain/security/truststore/staging_api_collaborate.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "test112233");

        //Send client's certificate
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/Users/aswain/security/certs/devuser_client_cert.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "test112233");

        System.out.println(System.getProperties());

        System.out.println("Invoking remote method confluence2.login via xml-rpc");

        Object result = xmlRpcClient.execute("confluence2.login", params);

        String loginToken = (String) result;
        System.out.println("loginToken : " + loginToken);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.err.println("JavaClient: " + exception);
    }

}
```

}

The password & path to view the *.jks files are correct.
Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: If you add -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to your client program it will probably tell you more about what is happening.

Comment: @NikolajHansen - I have done that already and pasted the "no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication" message from that log above.

Comment: Sorry didn&#39;t see that. Read this. Exactly the same error. So probably your server trusts tore does not have the public key of the client?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39096286/1700716

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39096286/1700716