# SSL Client Authentiction - no suitable certificate found even though my client certificate matches to the list in 'Cert Authorities'

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, sslhandshakeexception, truststore

This question may seem to be a duplicate of [Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869430/warning-no-suitable-certificate-found-continuing-without-client-authentication) 
but I'm experiencing a similar issue even when the client certificate was signed  by the signers mentioned in the **CertificateRequest** message.

I'm just curious to know whether using self signed certificates (not trusted by CA) for both client and server (tomcat) is a limitation to the client authentication ?

I am trying to establish a connection to HTTPS Server using Client Authentication through a self signed certificate **NOT trusted by any CA** (created using keytool).

I have set the properties for keystore and truststore (also enabled the 'debug' all)

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", 
"C:\\Users\\rmohanda\\Certificates\\composerClient.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",  
"C:\\Users\\rmohanda\\Certificates\\composerClient.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");`
```

At runtime, I'm facing an SSL Handshake exception as :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown 
     Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at InstallCert_ORG.main(InstallCert_ORG.java:102)
```

Client keystore :

```
  Loading Client KeyStore- C:\Users\rmohanda\Certificates\composerClient.jks    
  adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Composer Client, OU=Genesys Composer, O=Genesys Composer, 
  L="Chennai ", ST=TN, C=IN
  Issuer:  CN=Composer Client, OU=Genesys Composer, O=Genesys Composer, 
  L="Chennai ", ST=TN, C=IN
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x286e9e35
  Valid from Mon May 28 23:25:50 IST 2018 until Sat May 27 23:25:50 IST 2023
```

Debug Log :

```
 *** CertificateRequest
 Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
 Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, 
 signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, 
 signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, 
 SHA256withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x1), Unknown (hash:0x3, 
 signature:0x2), Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x3), SHA1withRSA, 
 SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
 Cert Authorities:
 <CN=Composer Client, OU=Genesys Composer, O=Genesys Composer, L="Chennai ", 
 ST=TN, C=IN>
 [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 171
 0000: 0D 00 00 A7 03 01 02 40   00 1E 06 01 06 02 06 03  .......@........
 0010: 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01   04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02  ................
 0020: 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03   00 81 00 7F 30 7D 31 0B  ............0.1.
 0030: 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13   02 49 4E 31 0B 30 09 06  0...U....IN1.0..
 0040: 03 55 04 08 13 02 54 4E   31 11 30 0F 06 03 55 04  .U....TN1.0...U.
 0050: 07 13 08 43 68 65 6E 6E   61 69 20 31 19 30 17 06  ...Chennai 1.0..
 0060: 03 55 04 0A 13 10 47 65   6E 65 73 79 73 20 43 6F  .U....Genesys Co
 0070: 6D 70 6F 73 65 72 31 19   30 17 06 03 55 04 0B 13  mposer1.0...U...
 0080: 10 47 65 6E 65 73 79 73   20 43 6F 6D 70 6F 73 65  .Genesys Compose
 0090: 72 31 18 30 16 06 03 55   04 03 13 0F 43 6F 6D 70  r1.0...U....Comp
 00A0: 6F 73 65 72 20 43 6C 69   65 6E 74                 oser Client
 *** ServerHelloDone
 [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
 0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
 Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client 
 authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 146, 75, 216, 252, 78, 7, 218, 254, 136, 127, 199, 
207, 80, 170, 251, 9, 188, 39, 206, 22, 74, 23, 63, 4, 39, 217, 73, 89, 143, 
4, 0, 116, 9, 234, 67, 240, 44, 91, 209, 165, 85, 22, 207, 75, 74, 86, 154, 
8, 239, 168, 138, 216, 35, 7, 56, 183, 7, 104, 139, 170, 104, 39, 229, 156 }
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 77
0000: 0B 00 00 03 00 00 00 10   00 00 42 41 04 92 4B D8  ..........BA..K.
0010: FC 4E 07 DA FE 88 7F C7   CF 50 AA FB 09 BC 27 CE  .N.......P....'.
```

Though the certificate authorities in certificate request matches the client certificate as state above under Client Keystore heading, I'm still getting the handshare exception

```
Cert Authorities:
 <CN=Composer Client, OU=Genesys Composer, O=Genesys Composer, L="Chennai ", 
 ST=TN, C=IN>
```

Certificate warning and eventually gets aborted with exception:

```
 Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client 
 authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

**Note :**  I have NOT signed the client and server certificates by CA. For testing purpose, I am just using the self signed certificates which is not trusted by any certificate authority.

> **UPDATE** :
>
> *Command:*    ***keytool -v -list -keystore composerClient.jks***

```
C:\Users\users\XXX>keytool -v -list -keystore composerClient.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: composerclient
Creation date: 28 May, 2018
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Composer Client, OU=Genesys Composer, O=Genesys Composer, 
L="Chennai ", ST=TN, C=IN
Issuer: CN=Composer Client, OU=Genesys Composer, O=Genesys Composer, 
L="Chennai ", ST=TN, C=IN
Serial number: 286e9e35
Valid from: Mon May 28 23:25:50 IST 2018 until: Sat May 27 23:25:50 IST 2023
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  88:69:29:39:6D:46:F9:C2:27:8B:2B:C5:C7:F2:90:EE
         SHA1: 3D:7A:39:C4:0C:C1:15:07:94:2B:D2:AE:05:E0:C8:77:D5:13:C1:8D
         SHA256: 
 CB:8D:CD:95:15:35:6C:90:16:DB:35:4B:95:30:
 DE:7B:F8:CC:01:F8:8C:64:A5:F4:AE:F6:93:DB:4E:DE:A4:72
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 13 CA AF 09 CF DE E6 F4   89 92 DF CC 8A 34 69 38  .............4i8
0010: 6F CB 4A E0                                        o.J.
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: tomcat
Creation date: 4 Jun, 2018
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=Tomcat SSLServer, OU=Genesys Tomcat, O=Genesys Tomcat, L=Daly 
City, ST=California, C=US
Issuer: CN=Tomcat SSLServer, OU=Genesys Tomcat, O=Genesys Tomcat, L=Daly 
City, ST=California, C=US
Serial number: 7c49521
Valid from: Mon May 28 23:20:46 IST 2018 until: Sat May 27 23:20:46 IST 2023
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  B9:68:14:FB:95:F5:E6:22:A9:07:32:AD:DA:7A:D6:DD
         SHA1: 75:05:3E:5D:20:32:57:34:D3:67:29:33:B9:30:DB:8F:07:FB:8E:9D
         SHA256: 
 A4:D6:AC:38:AD:47:78:D9:C0:0D:AD:CB:B3:27:3F:99:45:
 1A:73:C0:87:B6:0A:44:04:C3:FD:16:C7:98:9C:06
        Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
        Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 90 B1 89 D6 D2 EC 71 87   FD 46 09 B4 A0 BC A7 98  ......q..F......
0010: D7 C5 5C AD                                        ..\.
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************
```

Comment: are you sure that at the other end of your connection you are using same certs. Also anything else like expiry date , validaity date. Please check that

Comment: @SagarKharab, I have added the client certificate file (exported from JKS keystore) to the server keystore and vice versa.  I also double checked that certificates are not expired. In fact, I have created the certs a couple of days back with validity specified as **-validity 1825**.

Comment: Your client certificate does not include the certificate chain. Add the client certificate along with certificate chain in the keystore.

Comment: @pawindergupta ,  I'm using self signed certificates (which is not trusted by any CA) for both client and server and hence there is ONLY a single certificate associated for both client and server (no certificate chains exists for client and server).  

That said, I don't think that this could be an issue. Pls clarify if my understanding is wrong

Comment: Do you use the same keystore file for both client and server?

Comment: @pawindergupta : No, I have separate keystore for client and server (client.jks and server.jks).

Comment: Is your client certificate suitable for client authentication at all, i.e. does it have the appropriate key usage and extended key usage extensions? Please show the relevant parts of the certificate (for example the output of `openssl x509 -text -in ...`).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, How to view those informations ?  Could you pls text the full command ?

Comment: @Raguram: try `keystore -list -v`. This should also list the key usage etc extensions for the certificate

Comment: @SteffenUllrich,  

    **Extensions:**

     _#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
    SubjectKeyIdentifier [
    KeyIdentifier [
    0000: 13 CA AF 09 CF DE E6 F4   89 92 DF CC 8A 34 69 38  
    .............4i8
    0010: 6F CB 4A E0                                        o.J.
    ]
    ]_

    **Extensions:**

_  #1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
     SubjectKeyIdentifier [
    KeyIdentifier [
    0000: 90 B1 89 D6 D2 EC 71 87   FD 46 09 B4 A0 BC A7 98  
    ......q..F......
    0010: D7 C5 5C AD                                        ..\.
    ]
 ]_

Comment: @Raguram: this looks like a bit too few information. I would be expecting at least `KeyUsage` and `BasicConstraints` and probably other things. Can you please add the full output to your question and only redact things which clearly need to be redacted and explain what you've redacted unless its obvious?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I have updated my question to contain the output to the command **keytool -v -list -keystore composerClient.jks** for the client keystore (JKS). Please have a look and let me know if anythiny is wrong !

Comment: @Raguram: according to this the certificate has neither a BasicConstraints  nor a KeyUsage extension. I have no idea how you've created this certificate but this might be the reason the code is complaining.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I have created the certificates using keytool utility.  The command that I have used is :



`keytool -genkey -alias composerClient -keyalg RSA -validity 1825 -keystore composerClient.jks -storetype JKS`

Comment: @Raguram: try to recreate the certificate by adding  `-ext KeyUsage:critical="digitalSignature,keyCertSign,keyEncipherment" -ext BasicConstraints:critical="ca:true" -ext ExtendedKeyUsage=clientAuth` to your command.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I have created the JKS file by appending the parameters that you have given but still I'm getting the same error.  I could see the keyusage and extensions now after recreating the client JKS file using the given commands.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich,  `Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
  Key_CertSign
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 0A 9B 6A F4 74 0F ED B5   36 41 55 1E 34 25 B0 0A  ..j.t...6AU.4%..
0010: C4 2D 83 BA                                        .-..
]
]`

Comment: @Raguram: then I don't know either what the problem might be.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : If possible, could you please share some sources (or examples) for client authentication.  Your help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: @Raguram: does your keystore have the key pair inside?

Comment: @leaqui: yes, I do have the key pair inside the keystore !

Comment: @Raguram have you tried using same keystore at client and server?

Comment: @leaqui: Nope, that sounds weird.  At real time, keystore would differ at client and server.

Comment: @Raguram was this ever resolved? Facing same issue.

Comment: @DineshM Nope. I didn't get a chance to investigate this further.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, one possible cause of this error is if you're using an http client different than the standard java one (e.g. Apache HttpClient, REST Assured). Those clients have to be individually configured and will not just inherit keystore / truststore values set via the java.net.ssl properties.

Here is an example of setting the keystore for Apache's HttpClient ([adapted from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45541092/7293895)).

```
try (InputStream inStream = this.class.getResourceAsStream(KEYSTORE))
{
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE);
    ks.load(inStream, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(ks, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
    return HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
}
```

Comment: Apache HC does use the sysprops if you call `HttpClients.createSystem()` `HttpClientBuilder.useSystemProperties()` or `SSLContexts.createSystemDefault()`