# Certificate not being sent when making a SSL handshake

Tags: ssl

My application invokes a web service request. The provider of this web service is requesting for a certificate based authentication.

Unfortunately while making the handshake, the certificate is not being returned as part of the CertificateRequest step. Below is the log trace

```
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client
authentication
```

I have placed the keystore and the truststore using the below properties which is being picked up during the handshake (logged in the logs)

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$CMX_SSL_KEY_STORE
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456 
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12  

JAVA_OPTS= JAVA_OPTS="-D$PS_TOKEN$ENV_TOKEN $LOCAL_MEM_OPTS $GC_OPTS
$CMAX_OPTS $JMX_OPTS $CMX_SSL_TRUST_STORE_OPT $MQ_OPTS 
$ADDITIONAL_JVM_OPTS $LOCAL_JVM_OPTS $CMX_SSL_KEY_STORE_OPT"
```

I don't have a private key as part of the keystore, as the vendor who provided the certificate refused to provide the private key. As part of the keystore, I have the whole chain of the certificate, but still its not working

Error seen in the logs is as below

```
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
```

Need some guidance to resolve this issue

I looked at

> [why doesn't java send the client certificate during SSL handshake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299133/why-doesnt-java-send-the-client-certificate-during-ssl-handshake)

which is on the same problem, but the solution provided by Bruno is failing. Not able to attach the certificate to the private key using the same alias

Comment: **No private key -> no HTTPS certificate authentication.** You need a proper client certificate including private key for HTTPS certificate base client auth.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have a private key as part of the keystore

Then you don't have a keystore: you have a truststore.

> as the vendor who provided the certificate refused to provide the private key.

Of course he did. None of your beeswax.

You're supposed to provide your *own* private key and certificate in your own keystore.

You have a serious misunderstanding here.