# TLS Client Auth | Sectigo CA | Java

Tags: java, ssl

I generated a private key pair using KeyStore Explorer that was signed by Sectigo [formerly Comodo] yesterday. The goal is to employ this in an SSL mutual authentication scenario. I work with iWay, a java application, that will post messages to SAP's CPI, a service on cloud. The service on CPI has client authentication enabled [specific to the resource, not at host:port]. I have created a keystore with our private key and a truststore with some public certs in it. In response to a failed communication, I've enabled SSL debug on the application and here are my findings:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

This is reported at a stage when server cert was validated and accepted. In order to ensure whether or not the key in question took effect, I verified the logs and noticed the following, which assures that, it did [key name changed for security reasons]:

```
found key for : self_***.com_priv
```

I also verified that SAP accepts certificates when signed by valid CAs in the log that looked like this:

```
Cert Authorities:
...
<CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US>
...
```

This is how the signed cert look like, when opened on Windows:

[image]

I have the following questions:

1) The chain is displayed in the certificate when opened on Windows but not on KeyStore Explorer. Anyone know why?

2) The USERTrust root CA appears to be imported into SAP's trust store based on the log given above.  In the picture above, the root cert, although, reported as Sectigo, which happens to be a friendly name, has its issuer name conforming to the one imported onto SAP's trust store:

[image]

I hence am not sure why java will not render this cert to SAP during TLS handshake. Any thoughts please?

3) The intermediate certificate has a property named Authority Information Access, in which, a link to its root is present. The properties of this root is entirely different from that of the root I see in picture at item 2 above. Does this matter at all?

[image]

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was due to the way, I imported the CA Reply into my private key. I imported only the signed entity certificate while it looks like I must had imported in PEM format. Thanks to Bruno who have explained the resolution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299133/why-doesnt-java-send-the-client-certificate-during-ssl-handshake/9300727#9300727). I am relieved!