# Installing SSL certificate on a jboss 4.2 Legacy App

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, sha

I am trying to install our latest SSL certificate (from GoDaddy) on a legacy app however I am getting the following error:

```
No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
```

in Server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
    sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" ciphers="
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
    SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" 
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    keystoreFile="/usr/local/jboss/ssl.keystore" keystorePass="******"
           clientAuth="false" />
```

Do I need to install a new cipher suite into my jre? is there any easier solution?

Comment: What is your Java version? Try to install `JCE Unlimited Strength policy` files for you Java. It allows JVM to use stronger versions of existing algorithms.

Comment: I am using java-6-jrockit.

Comment: Try to install this JCE http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html if you do not have it already. You have to install it into that same JRE the JBoss uses.

Comment: Done, however sadly no luck. I tried without specifying the ciphers in my Server.xml too.

Comment: I think you have to investigate your keystore more closely, have look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297867/ssl-tomcat-certificate-error .Do you have just one key pair plus its certificate in /usr/local/jboss/ssl.keystore? Is keystore type `JKS`? Its is a long shot without more info.

Comment: My apologies, the error was a red-herring. I had modified my existing keystore file. I created a completely new keystore and re-keyed the certificate with a new csr and have got it working this way.

Comment: That's good, one less thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your certificate file to the truststore of the JVM your server is using.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10853655)

Comment: yeah, sorry, you are right.. .but as i couldnt comment i thought it was the correct way to get feedback from the poster.